# Time Limit Exceeded, Leetcode problem, 3Sum, 308 / 313 testcases passed, Why is it slow? Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, time

Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets `[nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]]` such that `i != j, i != k, and j != k, and nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0`.

Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

```
Example 1:

Input: nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
Output: [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]

Explanation:
nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2] = (-1) + 0 + 1 = 0.
nums[1] + nums[2] + nums[4] = 0 + 1 + (-1) = 0.
nums[0] + nums[3] + nums[4] = (-1) + 2 + (-1) = 0.
```

The distinct triplets are [-1,0,1] and [-1,-1,2].

Notice that the order of the output and the order of the triplets does not matter.

```
Example 2:

Input: nums = [0,1,1]
Output: []`
Explanation: The only possible triplet does not sum up to 0.
```

```
Example 3:

Input: nums = [0,0,0]
Output: [[0,0,0]]
Explanation: The only possible triplet sums up to 0.
```

I wrote my own version, but in the last tests I get a problem with execution time. At the same time, it seems to me that I broke the problem down into its component parts quite well and optimized them.

```
class Solution(object):
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        # I divide the list into positive and negative numbers
        less_nums = sorted(list(set(filter(lambda x: x < 0, nums))))
        more_nums = sorted(list(set(filter(lambda x: x > 0, nums))))
        complete = []
        # I get all possible options in the format [-n, 0, n]
        if 0 in nums:
            complete = map(lambda y: [y, 0, -y], filter(lambda x: -x in more_nums, less_nums))
        # I get all options in the format [n, n, 2n]
        even_nums = filter(lambda y: y % 2 == 0 and y != 0, list(set(nums)))
        map(lambda num: complete.append(sorted([-(num / 2), -(num / 2), num])), filter(lambda num: -(num / 2) in nums and len(filter(lambda u: u == -(num / 2), nums)) > 1, even_nums))
        # and I get all the other possible options, both with positive numbers and with negative ones
        for plus_num in more_nums:
            for min_num in filter(lambda z: -z < plus_num, less_nums):
                if (-(plus_num + min_num) in less_nums) and (-(plus_num + min_num) != min_num) and not(sorted([min_num, -(plus_num + min_num), plus_num]) in complete):
                    complete.append(sorted([min_num, -(plus_num + min_num), plus_num]))
        for min_num in less_nums:
            for plus_num in filter(lambda z: -z > min_num, more_nums):
                if (-(min_num + plus_num) in more_nums) and (-(min_num + plus_num) != plus_num) and not(sorted([min_num, -(min_num + plus_num), plus_num]) in complete):
                    complete.append(sorted([min_num, -(min_num + plus_num), plus_num]))
        
        # at the end I also check the option when there are three zeros in the list
        if len(filter(lambda x: x == 0, nums)) >= 3:
            complete.append([0, 0, 0])


        return complete
```

My question is exactly - WHY IS IT SLOW?
I cant understand why all use While. I know, that filter is faster than ussualy cycles, but anw

I don't understand why this solution works faster and passes all tests:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        nums.sort()
        ans = []
        n = len(nums)
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            if nums[i] > 0: break  # Since arr[i] <= arr[l] <= arr[r], if arr[i] > 0 then sum=arr[i]+arr[l]+arr[r] > 0
            l = i + 1
            r = n - 1
            while l < r:
                sum3 = nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r]
                if sum3 == 0:
                    ans.append([nums[i], nums[l], nums[r]])
                    while l+1 < n and nums[l+1] == nums[l]: l += 1  # Skip duplicates nums[l]
                    l += 1
                    r -= 1
                elif sum3 < 0: l += 1
                else: r -= 1
                
            while i+1 < n and nums[i+1] == nums[i]: i += 1  # Skip duplicates nums[i]
            i += 1
        return ans
```

Comment: One, of several reasons, is that you keep testing if things are in 'complete'  which you keep as a list.  Testing if something is in a list is a O(n) operation (it checks against each element).  Consider keeping complete as a set.

Comment: You can make minor changes to your code to improve performance **but** if your algorithm is fundamentally inefficient (which it is) then you're fighting a losing battle

Comment: @SIGHUP I understand, that's why I ask the question, what is my fundamental mistake?

Comment: @ChristianSloper I thought about this, but it confuses me that in the second example everything works faster and without using set

Comment: The second example uses two pointers in O(n) on each iteration of the outer loop for a total time complexity of O(n^2). Your solution is O(n^3).